# How to deserialise a byte array containing HTTP POST parameters from a .NET WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, serialization, webclient

I am sending an HTTP POST request to a remote URL using WebClient as follows:

```
byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(
                        "https://www.jaja.com/yadayadayada", "POST", reqparm);
responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
```

The URL gives a response in the form of HTTP POST parameters e.g:

> "Status=Ok&BrowserUrl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.jaja.com%3a7106%2fxxx&Hash=8614C21DD93749339906DB35C51B06006B33DC8C192F40DFE2DB6549942C837C4452E1D1333DE9DB7814B278C8B9E3C34D1A76D2F937DEE57502336E0A071412"

The problem I'm facing here is how do I serialise this response to an object for this class:

```
public class PaynowResponseModel : PayNowBase
    {
        public string browserurl { get; set; }
        public string pollurl { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string hash { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried the following method

```
public static object ByteArrayToObject(Byte[] buffer)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            object rval = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return rval;
        }
```

Which I'm calling this way:

```
var responseObj = (PaynowResponseModel) General.ByteArrayToObject(responsebytes);
```

But it's not working. I get an exception in the ByteArrayToObject method

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was caught
>   HResult=-2146233076   Message=The input stream is not a valid binary
>   format. The starting contents (in bytes) are:
>   73-74-61-74-75-73-3D-4F-6B-26-62-72-6F-77-73-65-72 ...
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerializationHeaderRecord.Read(__BinaryParser
>   input)
>          at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadSerializationHeaderRecord()
>          at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>          at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>          at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>          at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)

Please assist with how I can solve this problem or an alternative way of achieving my goal there.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly deserialize the byte array since the byte array is not a valid `PayNowResponseModel` serialized object.

Use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes))` in order to parse the retrieved string to a NameValueCollection, then create a converter to convert the data to `PayNowResponseModel` object.
[You might need to add a reference to System.Web]

Take a look at the following sample:

```
        var resp = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responsebytes);
        var converted = new PaynowResponseModel();
        converted.browserurl = resp["BrowserUrl"];
        converted.status = resp["Status"];
        converted.hash = resp["Hash"];
```

Comment: Awesome this is the perfect solution. Simple and to the point. Thank you very much